# Replace a percentage of elements in a raster per the existing values in R

Tags: r, matrix, raster

I have a RasterLayer that contains values 1:5. I would like to randomly select 10% of cells that hold the value of 3 and convert these to contain 6's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where raster is the RasterLayer Object.

We find the cells which are equal to 3 using `raster[raster[]==3]`

We then replace it with a vector of the same length, randomly sampling either 3 or 6 with probabilities of 90% and 10% respectively.

```r
raster[raster[]==3] <- sample(c(3, 6),
                              size = length(raster[raster[]==3]),
                              replace  = T,
                              prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
```